# Controlling SSRS using TFS 2013

Tags: reporting-services, source-control-explorer

I am using TFS 2013 for source control and am trying to figure out how I can back store the source code for my reports on TFS.  I want other users to be able to pull the source code to be able to modify a report or use it as the starting point for a new derivative.

I can't really seem to find any good solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Visual Studio 2013 together with [SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856966.aspx).

This will give you the possibility to create SSRS projects in Visual Studio and add them to TFS source control.

Comment: I have found that in SQL Server Data Tools I am able to natively connect and use TFVC repos, and with Git Extensions push to a git repo on TFS.  However the git extensions route it a bit clunky and not user friendly.  Has anyone used Git Extensions and if so is it reliable.